# How to make a DIV stick to the side of a fixed width element in an otherwise-fluid design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got a fluid content area with padding and a fixed-width sidebar.  I'm wanting to `float: right` an image and give it a negative `margin-right` equal to the container's `padding` to get the floated image to abut the sidebar.

Code is worth a thousand words...

Here's a reduced test case is here that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/alexdunae/34ZDw/3/  -- shrink or expand the preview pane to see.

It's seems that my negative margin calculation must be off somewhere.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're mixing percentages and pixels. Try converting all your absolute `px` values into percentages.

Comment: just to make sure i understand, you want the page content to have a varying width , and on the right side - you want a 180px floating div/image? when you scroll does it need to stay or scroll too?

Comment: @galchen: check out Alex's fiddle -- the css portion documents the problem very clearly in comments.

Comment: just to make sure i get it straight - you want the grey div to be aligned to the right of the content (ie touch the pink sidebar)?

Comment: @Blender I don't want the sidebar fluid, it should be fixed.

Comment: @galchen that's right, if you set the width of `#main` to 700px it does it.

Answer (score 1):

set the 8.xxx% side padding on the siblings of the image instead of the parent `#inner`, that way you don't need the negative margin

http://jsfiddle.net/34ZDw/9/

```
#inner > p {
    padding: 0 8.571428571429%;
}

...

.alignright {
    float: right;
    width: 53.75%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 0; /* <-- this to 0 */
    padding: 0.3125em 0 0.3125em 0.3125em; /* now you can also add your padding */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty good.  I'm at the mercy of WordPress + clients with dubious technical skill so my main concern is breakage when they insert some unexpected tag.  Maybe `#inner > *' setting the padding, plus `#inner .alignright` with 0 padding would work.  I'll experiment and post back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hopefully i understood what you're looking for....

i normally try to avoid using tables in building the layout of the page but in that case, if you want a changing width, it's either that or javascript with divs.

having the grey box stuck on the right side of the content box is not too complicated if you remember one rule: place fixed content first.

what i've done is having the grey box floated right inside the #inner box, which will have 0 padding and margins. whatever will go inside - will have the necessary padding.

NOTE: IE 6 does not handle side margins properly, so i always try to avoid them (and use padding instead).

here's my suggested code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
#layout { width: 100%; border: none; }
#layout #sidebar { width: 180px; }
#inner { float: left; width: auto; background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1); }
#inner p { padding: 0 8.571428571429%; margin: 0px; }
#sidebar { width: 180px; background: rgba(0,0,255, 0.1); }
.alignright { float: right; width: 53.75%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); color: #fff; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="layout">
    <tr>
        <td id="inner" valign="top">
           <p>Fluid width with 8.571428571429% L/R padding</p>
           <p>Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula egestas tincidunt. Nullam risus magna, ornare vitae varius eget, scelerisque a libero. Morbi eu porttitor ipsum.</p>
           <div class="alignright">Here is some aligned-right goodness.</div>
           <p>Nullam lorem nisi, posuere quis volutpat eget, luctus nec massa. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia tellus sit amet bibendum. Ut posuere justo in enim pretium scelerisque. Etiam ornare vehicula euismod. Vestibulum at risus augue. Sed non semper dolor. Sed fringilla consequat velit a porta. Pellentesque sed lectus pharetra ipsum ultricies commodo non sit amet velit. Suspendisse volutpat lobortis ipsum, in scelerisque nisi iaculis a. Duis pulvinar lacinia commodo. Integer in lorem id.</p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <td id="sidebar" valign="top">
            <p>Fixed width 180px sidebar</p>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see - the elements INSIDE the #inner element will receive the needed padding

i used a table for the layout to avoid javascript. i must state that i would prefer going the js way.

hope that solves it for you

Comment: Interesting idea –– I've drunk so much web standards Kool-aid that I never considered a table.  You've got me wondering if I could do this with `display: table` and friends to stay pure.  You also put the padding on the child elements, like @mdmullinax did. Thanks for the suggestion. (Here's the JSfiddle for future searchers looking to explore: http://jsfiddle.net/alexdunae/AeL2B/)